# AWS Cognito app client to restrict so it can't register users

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have Cognito user pool and deferent App clients for different usage is there a way I can restrict App client so it can support login but not sign up functionality?

Answer (score 1):

[Aws Cognito- Only allow admins to create users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCXZc.png)

During setup you can change the setting or update the existing setting so that only admins can create users

Comment: set up of user pull or app client?